# Unable to display all the rows in my netbeans jtable from sql

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable, actionlistener

I want to display all 5 columns of my SQL database table `bk_det` in my `jtable` which is in netbeans ide in java language but I am only able to display 4 columns instead of 5. What is the problem can any one help m posting the code below:

```
 private void btviewbkdetActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if(evt.getSource()==btviewbkdet){
    try {
            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
            Connection con = util.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from bk_det");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
            Vector columns_name = new Vector();
            Vector data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int i=1; i< columns; i++){
            columns_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
            }
            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);

            while(rs.next()){
            data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int j=1; j< columns; j++){
            data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
            }
            dtm.addRow(data_rows);
            }
            tblbnkdet.setModel(dtm);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        // TODO add your handling code here:
}
    }

    private void btbkrepviewActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
if(evt.getSource()==btviewbkdet){
    try {
            DBUtil util = new DBUtil();
            Connection con = util.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from dbo.bk_rep");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmetadata = rs.getMetaData();
            int columns = rsmetadata.getColumnCount();
            DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel();
            Vector columns_name = new Vector();
            Vector data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int i=1; i< columns; i++){
            columns_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
            }
            dtm.setColumnIdentifiers(columns_name);

            while(rs.next()){
            data_rows = new Vector();
            for(int j=1; j< columns; j++){
            data_rows.addElement(rs.getString(j));
            }
            dtm.addRow(data_rows);
            }
            tblbkrep.setModel(dtm);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
            Logger.getLogger(Demo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        // TODO add your handling code here:
}        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't `for(int i=1; i< columns; i++)` be `for(int i=1; i<= columns; i++)`?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the change

```
 for(int i=1; i<= columns; i++){
    columns_name.addElement(rsmetadata.getColumnName(i));
 }
```